# Easeljs - touch events are not working in tablet and android - but why

Tags: javascript, android, ipad, easeljs

I'm using a framework called easeljs to develop a canvas application - which allows you to draw a freehand shape on the screen.

Its working in desktop, but not in tablet or android. Its as if the touch events are not working.

Works fine in desktop

```
this.colourPallette.addEventListener('click', this.palletteHandler);



$('.gs-hamburger').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.gs-hamburger').toggleClass('gs-close');
            $('#gs-nav-static-hamburger').toggleClass('gs-nav-right-appear');
            $('main,#gs-navfix,#gs-nav-static').toggleClass('gs-nav-right-appear');
            $('#gs-nav-right').toggleClass('gs-appear');
        });
```

Do I need to unbind the events first - to avoid double triggering? And then BIND "click touchstart"

what about the addEventListener - would I just chain it with 'click touchstart'?

Something like this?

```
//__clean start
$(".selectorChoice").unbind('touchstart click');


//__ experienced journey selectors
$(".selectorChoice").bind('touchstart click', function(){

    //do other stuff            
    return false;
});
```

Would something like this also work? Would I need to integrate touchpunch - or is this only when using jquery ui?

```
this.colourPallette.addEventListener('click touchstart', this.palletteHandler);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled touch on the Stage?

`createjs.Touch.enable(stage);`

This proxies Windows, iOS, and Android touch events to the regular mouse handler methods.

http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Touch.html